# Excel - Is it possible to make characters appear as "*" in a range?

Tags: vba, excel

Does anyone know if it's possible to make the text that is input into an Excel range appear as "*******"?  I want users to be able to enter a password into a range to sign in (without a Userform), but I want the characters to be asterisks (*) when the user types so that it can't be seen.

I'll use a Userform as a last resort, but I'd like to try to do this without a Userform first.

Can anyone offer any help?

Thank you!

Comment: The OnChange event only fires after the cell has been edited, so their password would appear as plain text until they exited the cell. Then it would be fairly easy to store that cell's value in a variable and replace the cell's text with asterisks. Will that work?

Comment: You can use this custom cell format  `;;;**` but the password will still be visible in the formula bar

Comment: Just a comment too - if this is going to be a secure document, please be aware that Excel's Locking/Protection is basically a joke if you are determined to get in there.  Also, there will be other ways people could perhaps get the data.  If this is for a test/nothing super sensitive, then you're probably fine...just thought to mention.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks!  This will work nicely.  I saw some other wierd custom formats like this in my google searches, but they're pretty cryptic.  And I plan on checking "Hidden" on the Protection tab of the cell so taht when the worksheet is protected it won't be able to be seen in the formula bar.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BruceWayne Good point, but fortunately, there won't be anything super sensitive contained in the range.

Comment: @TimWilliams - Would doing `Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False` avoid the Formula bar issue?

Comment: @BruceWayne That or just checking "Hidden" in the Protection tab of the Format Cells dialogue box.  It requires protecting the worksheet to take effect, though.

Comment: Yes but that's not a very user-friendly solution.  Basically trying to hide the password without using some more advanced coding is not going to work if someone has *any* interest at all in seeing it.

Comment: http://www.learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2014/06/excel-cell-masking-for-password/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility could be to use text box ActiveX control in the Sheet with `PasswordChar` property set to e.g. `*`. Then the text user enters in the text box will be displayed as `*`. The text box can be formated so it has the same size as the containing cell and it will be sized when containing cell size changes etc. `Linked-cell` can be used so the password value can be read from this cell.

[image]

Comment: Great suggestion!  Thanks, dee!  I'm going to implement this suggestion.  By the way, can you elaborate on how you make the text box's size change with the containing cell?  I checked "Move and size with cells" when I right click on the text box (in Designer mode) and choose "Format Control" and go to the "Properties" tab.  That property didn't cause the text box to automatically resize when I resize the containing cell.  Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: "Move and size with cells", yes that was my idea as well. If that doesn't work then as workaround: could you lock the structure of the sheet so the width/height of rows can't be changed by the user? Or via VBA handle `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event and check if `Target` intersects with the cell for password and ensure the size of text box coresponds with the size of the cell?

Answer (score 1):

Doing this without a userform is less than ideal because this code will get run every time something on the sheet changes. strPassword gets dimensioned as a global variable and *must* be Dim'd at the top of your code.

```
Dim strPassword As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value <> "********" Then
        strPassword = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value
        Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value = "********"
    End If
    MsgBox strPassword
End Sub
```

If there's room on your sheet, adding this code to a button (ie, `Button1_Click` event) that would read the password and replace the cell value would prevent the code from running with every change.

Comment: Ooh, could you also perhaps add `Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False`? Then, when a user is typing into a cell, the formula bar won't show the characters.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Tim!  I like Tim William's comment above because it doesn't require any code to run - I'm fine with macros, I'd just rather opt for the simpler solution.  Thanks, though!